# Fill in missing dates between two sequential dates in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a data set that has a date column in which the date is only recorded when it changes, meaning that any NAs are assumed to be equal to the most recently recorded date. I want to fill in missing dates based on that logic. Here's an example of what the data might look like:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10/2/2015 | A1 |
| NA | A2 |
| NA | A3 |
| NA | A4 |
| 10/3/2015 | B1 |
| NA | B2 |
| NA | B3 |

And here's the desired result:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10/2/2015 | A1 |
| 10/2/2015 | A2 |
| 10/2/2015 | A3 |
| 10/2/2015 | A4 |
| 10/3/2015 | B1 |
| 10/3/2015 | B2 |
| 10/3/2015 | B3 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr`:

```
 df %>% 
      tidyr::fill(Date)
```

or

```
tidyr::fill(df, Date)
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  Date      Value
  <chr>     <chr>
1 10/2/2015 A1   
2 10/2/2015 A2   
3 10/2/2015 A3   
4 10/2/2015 A4   
5 10/3/2015 B1   
6 10/3/2015 B2   
7 10/3/2015 B3
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you!